# Loop through fields in field layout when `entry` is not set

Tags: templating, field, loop

Is there a way in a template to loop through the fields in a field layout without having to tie them to an entry? I'm currently grabbing that list with `entry.getFieldLayout(3).getFields()`, but that only works when `entry` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by reaching through the section and entry type to the final field layout. Like this:

```
{% set section = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('sectionName') %}
{% set entryType = '' %}
{% for type in section.getEntryTypes %}
    {% if type.handle == 'entryType' %}
        {% set entryType = type %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set fieldLayout = craft.fields.getLayoutById(entryType.fieldLayoutId) %}
```

You should be abel to use `getFields` as normal.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks. I'm glad I asked. It would have taken me forever (or possibly never) to figure that out on my own.